# Update composite foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have a self referencing model with composite primary key in ASP.NET MVC 3 using code first approach:

```
public class Area
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to have a controller with create and edit operations that can work with all properties, including the composite `Parent` (that must be previously added to the database).

I managed to get the create method running, but for editing the complex field doesn't want to update. The input data for the following method successfully parses to the object `area` that also has `area.Parent.Id1` and `area.Parent.Id2` set.

Current code that doesn't save changes for modifications to `Parent`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Area area)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (area.Parent != null)
                {
                    area.Parent = db.Areas.Find(area.Parent.Id1, area.Parent.Id2);
                    if (area.Parent == null)
                        throw new NotFoundException();
                    // need to mark it as modified...
                }
                db.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (NotFoundException)
        {
            //...
        }
        return View(area);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of workaround if anyone needs it. Add this to the model:

```
    [ForeignKey("Parent"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Parent_Id1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Parent_Id2 { get; set; }
```

And add this where it says "need to mark it as modified":

```
                    area.Parent_Id1 = area.Parent.Id1;
                    area.Parent_Id2 = area.Parent.Id2;
```